# angular scrollTop ng-repeat data flicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to create facebook like reverse infinite scroll solution for chat history, but i have run into problem.

I have a fairly simple code.

1.) Get current div scrollHeight

2.) push data into array | ng-repeat updates data

3.) update scrollTop

And everything sort of works, except that i have to use timeout to get updated scrollHeight and then it causes a flicker

http://lightzam.github.io/zInfiniteScroll/example04_normalScroll_inverse.html

This is what i mean by flicker. It renders data first and then does the scrollTop. So my question is how can i get the updated scrollHeight before ng-repeat updates the view.